# Binary search implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

Is there a better way to implement a binary search than I am in my code? My function is taking two two lists - `first_booth_voters` and `second_booth_voters` with `second_booth_voters` being sorted and `first_booth_voters` not sorted. I feel like I am making an unnecessary amount of comparisons.

```
from classes import VoterList

def fraud_detect_bin(first_booth_voters, second_booth_voters):
    fraud = VoterList()
    comparisons = 0

    for i in range(0, len(second_booth_voters)):
        item = second_booth_voters[i]
        first = 0
        last = len(second_booth_voters) - 1

        while first <= last:
            midpoint = (first + last) // 2

            if first_booth_voters[midpoint] == item:
            comparisons += 1
            fraud.append(first_booth_voters[midpoint])
            break 
        else:
            if item < first_booth_voters[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
                comparisons += 2
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
                comparisons += 2

    return fraud, comparisons
```

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32090492/1558022

Comment: What is `VoterList`?

Comment: OP commented on SO "ahh crap I've copied and pasted the wrong version." Apparently here is still the wrong version, though on SO indentation remains wrong.

Comment: @JanneKarila Even if the indentation is fixed, there is still a bug. This question should be closed :/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this, it's a redundant duplicate

```
for i in range(0, len(second_booth_voters)):
    item = second_booth_voters[i]
```

Instead use Python's `for value in iterable` syntax that lets you directly get the value of each list item for each iteration.

```
for item in second_booth_voters:
```

Also you should include a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).